# Hibernate Mapping Exception : Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, persistence, hibernate-mapping

There is a mapping exception for a particular entity.
Cant figure out from where the problem is arising.
I checked all the mappings 3 times from start to end.
Still i am getting a Mapping Exception.

Email to employee  is mapped only once.
but still it is reporting the error repeated mapping

Error is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.cluster.entity.Email column: EMPLOYEE_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:680)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:702)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1287)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775)
    at com.cluster.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    ... 1 more
```

**Email Pojo**

```
package com.cluster.entity;

public class Email {

    private int intEmailID;
    private String strEmailName;

    //many to one
    private EmailType emailType;

    //many to one
    private Employee employee;

    public int getIntEmailID() {
        return intEmailID;
    }

    public void setIntEmailID(int intEmailID) {
        this.intEmailID = intEmailID;
    }

    public String getStrEmailName() {
        return strEmailName;
    }

    public void setStrEmailName(String strEmailName) {
        this.strEmailName = strEmailName;
    }

    public EmailType getEmailType() {
        return emailType;
    }

    public void setEmailType(EmailType emailType) {
        this.emailType = emailType;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

**email.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        '-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN'
        'http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd'>


<hibernate-mapping package="com.cluster.entity" >
    <class name="Email" table="EMAIL">

        <id name="intEmailID" column="EMAIL_ID"> 
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">EMAIL_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="strEmailName" column = "EMAIL_NAME"/>

        <many-to-one name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE_ID" not-null = "true" class = "Employee"/>

        <many-to-one name="emailType" column="EMAIL_TYPE_ID" not-null = "true" class = "EmailType"/>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Related Script**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
  EMPLOYEE_ID      NUMBER                       NOT NULL,
  FIRSTNAME        VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)            NOT NULL,
  LASTNAME         VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)            NOT NULL,
  DATE_OF_BIRTH    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)            NOT NULL,
  SALARY           VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)            NOT NULL,
  DEPARTMENT_ID    NUMBER                       NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE EMAIL
(
 EMAIL_ID              NUMBER              NOT NULL,
 EMAIL_NAME            VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)   NOT NULL,
 EMPLOYEE_ID           NUMBER              NOT NULL,
 EMAIL_TYPE_ID         NUMBER              NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE EMAIL_TYPE
(
 EMAIL_TYPE_ID         NUMBER              NOT NULL,
 EMAIL_TYPE_NAME       VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)   NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD 
(
 CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE_ID
 PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE EMAIL_TYPE ADD 
(
 CONSTRAINT PK_EMAIL_TYPE_ID
 PRIMARY KEY (EMAIL_TYPE_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE EMAIL ADD
(
 CONSTRAINT PK_EMAIL_ID
 PRIMARY KEY (EMAIL_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE EMAIL ADD
( 
 CONSTRAINT FK_EMAIL_EMPLOYEE_ID
 FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
 REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE EMAIL ADD
( 
 CONSTRAINT FK_EMAIL_EMAIL_TYPE_ID
 FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL_TYPE_ID)
 REFERENCES EMAIL_TYPE (EMAIL_TYPE_ID)
);
```

Email to employee  is mapped only once.
but still it is reporting the error repeated mapping

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you set the collection in Employee as inverse?

```
<bag name="emails" inverse="true">
  <key column="EMPLOYEE_ID" not-null="true">
  ...
</bag>
```

Comment: inverse means that the Child (Email) is responsible for the association. so the child is owner of `EMPLOYEE_ID` and has to insert/update it. the parent only uses the field to knwo its children, but does not insert/update it

Comment: Similarly, I had the `@JoinColumn` on both sides of my bi-directional relationship.  However, that ambiguous error message sent me on a wild goose chase that just ended here.

Answer (score 8):

For those who are using annotations to solve this, the classes should look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Email {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int intEmailID;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int employeeId;

    @ManyToOne
    private EmailType emailType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employeeId")
    private Employee employee;

    // Getters and Setter
}


@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="employeeId")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private List<Email> emailList;

    public void setEmailList(List<Email> emailList) {
        this.emailList = emailList
    }

    public List<Email> getEmailList() {
        return emailList;
    }

    // Rest of getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have mapped `Employee` to `Email` using oneToMany relation. If yes its nothing wrong but you have to make sure you can insert and update only in one direction

should be mapped with `insert="false" update="false"` in `Employee`

Comment: yes...
you are right!
i tried it out..
we should either do inverse = "true",
or do as you have said!